# How to create and use list in Azure API-manager policy?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, policy, azure-policy

**Background**:
I am defining an API in Azure API Management.
I have defined a policy on "All operations" level. This policy does a couple of things. One of the things it does is setting a variable in the context object, so I can re-use the variable in when condition.

**What I need help with:**

How can I define a list in Azure API-M policy, which I can refer to in when condition?

**Code example**:

All operations policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable name="someList" value="[a,b,c,d]" />
        <when condition="@(context.Variables["someList"].Contains("a"))"
        </when>
        <otherwise>
        </otherwise>
    </inbound>
</policies>
```

It seems that my issue is that the variable "someList" is not recognized as an array, but as a String = "[a,b,c,d]". So basically, it will return true if the condition would say Contains("[").

I have also tried to store value as named values, but named values can't contain a Array as value.

What I want to achieve is keeping a list of subscriptions, so that I can match incoming subscription key in request to a list of pre-defined subscription keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the context.Variables['somelist'] as a list before using .ContainsKey('key').
I never needed to parse a list, so you have to google it how to do it, use keywords like C# and Dictionary or List for this, but i've done some parsing as JObject and int like this.

```
@{
   int myvar = context.Variables["var"];
   return myvar > 5;
}
```

And

```
@((int)context.Variables("year") < 2022)
```

Api management offers you the GetValueOrDefault<Type>("ParameterName", "DefaultValueIfNull") method to let you capture a header, variable or query and parse it directly, you'll find it here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the value of someList to `JArray` in the condition.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <base />
    <set-variable name="someList" value="[a,b,c,d]" />
    <when condition="@(JArray.Parse((string)context.Variables["someList"]).Contains("a"))">
    </when>
    <otherwise>
    </otherwise>
</inbound>
```